# data-* value for each class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 div's

```
<div class='class' data-color='gray'>
</div>

<div class='class' data-color='red'>
</div>
```

As you can see both `data-color` both have separate values. The first being `gray` and the second being `red`.

This is what I have done in my JavaScript (jQuery) to use it:

```
$(".class").each(function(){
    var DivDataColor = $(".class").data("color");
    $(this).css({'background': DivDataColor});
});
```

This makes them both have a gray color, what I think is happening is that it's just taking the first div's datatype and then applying that to both.

So just for trys I put the variable outside of the `.each()` function

```
var DivDataColor = $(".class").data("color");
$(".class").each(function(){
    $(this).css({'background': DivDataColor});
});
```

But I still had no luck, what could be the work around?

Comment: Interesting that you correctly used `$(this).css(...)` but still used `$(".class").data(...)`. I wonder why?

Comment: @FelixKling Not sure, guess my brain just derped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".class").each(function(){
    var DivDataColor = $(".class").data("color");
    //                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
    $(this).css({'background': DivDataColor});
});
```

Here you're re-selecting all the matching elements. Then, because there can only be one `"data-color"` value, yes, the first is being used.

Use `$(this)`, as you did below it:

```
$(".class").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var DivDataColor = $this.data("color");
    $this.css({'background': DivDataColor});
});
```

Alternatively, and most excellently, roll the operation into one, by taking an inverse approach:

```
$(".class").css("background", function() {
    return $(this).data("color");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `this` object inside the `.each()` call to access the  `data-color` attribute of the referenced object in the `.each()` call

```
$(".class").each(function(){
        var DivDataColor = $(this).data("color");
        $(this).css({'background': DivDataColor});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Think opposite, return the data attribute in the callback for setting the style

```
$(".class").css('background', function() {
    return $(this).data('color');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".class").each(function(){
    var DivDataColor = $(this).data("color"); 
    $(this).css({'background': DivDataColor});
});
```

replace '.class' by this

Answer (score 0):

Your first example seems to work with just a minor edit:

Keep the `DivDataColor` variable within your "each" loop, but instead of reselecting the `.class` class, use the variable `"this"`:

```
$(this).data("color")
```

Here is a working jsbin example: (http://jsbin.com/yuvetepo/1/edit).